# how can i enter a char which is part of a word in the list and print it out?

Tags: python, syntax, logic, project

im trying to make hangman as my little own project and i dont know how to enter a char which is part of some word from the list and print the char out. How could i do that?

```
import random

answer = input("Hi, wanna play? Y/N: ")


if answer == "N" or answer == "n":
print("ok")

elif answer == "Y" or answer == "y":

list = ["hey", "hello", "hi"]
list = random.choice(list)
len(list) == print(len(list) * "-")
print(len(list))
answer = input("ok, guess a letter: ")

if answer == list:
    print("good")
else:
    print("bad")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple in Python:

```
if character in word:
  #do stuff
  print(character)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need for this game is what follows(I have edited your code):

```py
import random
import re
answer = input("Hi, wanna play? Y/N: ")
if answer == "N" or answer == "n":
  print("ok")

elif answer == "Y" or answer == "y":
  myList = ["heyyyy", "helloo", "hiii"]
  myWord = random.choice(myList)
  emptyDash = "-" *len(myWord) 
  print(emptyDash)
  while emptyDash != myWord:
    answer = input("ok, guess a letter: ")
    if answer in myWord and answer != "":
        print("good")
        emptyDash = list(emptyDash)
        indicies = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(answer, myWord)]
        for value in indicies:
          emptyDash[value] = answer
        emptyDash = "".join(emptyDash)
        print(emptyDash)
    else:
        print("bad")
```

##### Example output:

```
Hi, wanna play? Y/N: Y
------
ok, guess a letter: h
good
h-----
ok, guess a letter: i
bad
ok, guess a letter: y
good
h-yyyy
ok, guess a letter: e
good
heyyyy
```

Note that you should not assign any value to predefined variables such as `list`, `dict`, and etc. Also, I have used the regex module to find the occurrences of the character in the word.

Additionally, you should not assign variables using double equal sign (`==`). This sign is just to make a logical statement.

Comment: looks good, but how can it print out more charachters at once when theres for example two "l's" in the word it just prints out one "l"

Comment: @Martin yea, you're right. The previous version of my answer did not support what you said. I have edited as per your comment. Hope it is what you seek.

Answer (score -1):

To check if a character is in a word:

```
if char in word:
    print(char)
```